# download individual `.deb` package file for integrity verification

Tags: deb, source-packages, checksums

I have system runtime measurements which shows what files of the packages have been executed by the system. I want to verify the checksum calculated by the Linux kernel's Integrity Management Architecture (IMA) against official checksum of the package files from ubuntu repos.

example of measurements below:

```
10 bae6e0fe76b1eb0864410323fc013c83ca626a66 ima-ng sha256:c1b65dd1aae2d422d1c6a3b9ae4c50f9cbf25108b8051c5be280ebfe32981456 /usr/bin/dircolors
10 71e4941190fb8601a55f5bc8b6ab284d40df3be9 ima-ng sha256:00fba26dcaa2f6832987e9421c9aa42d9f4d47652e4a25fdf1b92f935ac81989 /usr/bin/sudo
10 d8eb38a20ee87ddf87f20218642cc9059f74cefa ima-ng sha256:212eabe6f44f9e8b720b105c9dbcb9fc67fcc7be5250e608b88b33e8ac436d5a /usr/bin/su
10 a80c90a7f139cd62a1cb0f40adc6dae4f11e535b ima-ng sha256:b4642f4f56e37a506f758a0fce4054ed91470e6ac35fe940eaf18da4883d2d95 /usr/bin/groups
10 5fa6842bd391b0ea52448754bf78cad87754df73 ima-ng sha256:5ae83908197820124d467db6ecc821402d667dd4617d8fab3f0e30dc5ef5a074 /usr/bin/git
10 76101b9b21175328d4f2df1b3aa8002492c7a7b3 ima-ng sha256:65481459b05f8898299b7ef354138dc2ab674438d74cc4c8bf5aeef09a0331e8 /usr/bin/nano
10 84e18b01843fda8fd130e0a500607e55e3aeb16a ima-ng sha256:c2a2db43da333527632872c629465e0fb3f5cbf87115836a7fcda428877589a5 /usr/bin/python3.11
10 45737dc3d038bac2a5e40d085accdd545a692fbd ima-ng sha256:afd18e93eaf9dbea58ce345a2add190efc1b000558dba084417904415439e875 /usr/bin/tpm2
10 b3e35da87c02c9841d2f991e816feb055874d190 ima-ng sha256:db905ca30da311c0bcd005b3d475d22e6fa395c3205ff5f17cdd9a02d830e1fb /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-12
```

where do I find the checksum of individual files of an Ubnutu package. Lets suppose there is a package [g++-12](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/g++-12) and I can clearly see its provided sha1 & sha256 [checksums](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/amd64/g++-12/download). But Is there any resource which also provides the checksum of all the [individual files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/amd64/g++-12/filelist) of the package?
I can of course download the .deb file and extracts the contents and calculate manually but  its not very efficient solution of my use case.

Comment: Maybe explain why you need the checksum of individual files, since right now we don't know your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for attention the description has been updated for clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The Debian package system (`dpkg` and `.deb` packages) generates `MD5` sums internally when packages are installed. Unfortunately, your output only generates `SHA1` and `SHA256` sums. For this to work, you have to get the measurement to provide `MD5` sums for the files.

What happens is that when you install a package with `apt`/`dpkg`, an `.md5sums` file is generated for the package inside the directory `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

This means you can easily check the `MD5` sum for all files as they were when the packages was installed. This can be used to determine if any of the files have been altered *after* the packages was installed.

An example from my own system (Ubuntu 22.04.2). If I run `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/sudo.md5sums` I get this:

```
e8e2fd5938804db1abb67773f84f5549  usr/bin/cvtsudoers
8176b78ba666fb64e72a3ae6a4851793  usr/bin/sudo
7cd774a8abe0586bdd75fb90c8bcaec7  usr/bin/sudoreplay
3f90917a245d4aafe98bb39a1fb9fa09  usr/include/sudo_plugin.h
9eb3041fcbb7ba1a64664d7a7a13cc15  usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sudo.conf
8ccb24178b5cef512ac3fef3ad3b44f1  usr/libexec/sudo/audit_json.so
fc97536f5bf479b310cbffd9c5f030ec  usr/libexec/sudo/group_file.so
4410a4f7ce928d5cbc79b5881e26194b  usr/libexec/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0.0.0
c087bda8ff9210f79a94176ca817a4c8  usr/libexec/sudo/sample_approval.so
d8d8ca3f48bda0bb8a3e782379230284  usr/libexec/sudo/sesh
091c0ce05a872050dbe145bf156cea90  usr/libexec/sudo/sudo_intercept.so
d42066a08c1877f738c4c55c570f78e7  usr/libexec/sudo/sudo_noexec.so
4e920ee4b000c0bd9a1659a4368d5fdf  usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
59df52d5f1b4b01740df4abb34294711  usr/libexec/sudo/system_group.so
2f3db27567e8b72955cdccafb8d4750b  usr/sbin/sudo_logsrvd
8f778373024750a98f7412593ac7fa39  usr/sbin/sudo_sendlog
e46edcfbb954c4bd8a599d3d76d53d9a  usr/sbin/visudo

... (33 more lines omitted)
```

If you could get measurement you run to provide `MD5` sums for the files, you could check this value against the values provided in the `.md5sums` file.

If this is not possible, then it's unfortunate that the `dpkg` utility uses the old `MD5` hashes, while the kernel can not output these. In this case there might not be a better solution than to calculate the `SHA256` checksums yourself directly from the `.deb` files.